# How can I build a priority queue with C++ which gives priority to even big number then to small odd number?

Tags: c++, data-structures, computer-science

How can I build a priority queue with C++ which gives priority to even big numbers then to small odd number?

For example: if I push `4 8 3 2 1` into priority queue, in the priority queue it becomes `8 4 2 1 3`

Comment: first make a priority queue then overload the operator or function that determines priority (probably `operator<`) to have whatever rule you want it to have.

Comment: What @YoungJohn said. And just to be clear, don't write the priority queue yourself. Use [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: `8 4 2 1 3` or `8 4 2 3 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct greater_even_first{
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const{
        if(a%2==0){
            if(b%2)
                return true;
            else
                return a>b;
        }
        else if(b%2==0)
            return false;
        return b>a;
    }
};

#include<queue>
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, greater_even_first> name;
```

`greater_even_first` could be template to become more universal.

If you want know how it works read [`priority_queue`'s documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/).

Comment: That `operator ()` should be `const`.

Comment: This isn't quite what the user is looking for. Even numbers sort largest first, then odd numbers need to sort smallest first.

Comment: how do I undo a suggested edit, I made a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::priority_queue` and a custom comparator.

```
template<class T>
struct your_comparator {
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const {
        if((lhs & 1) == 0 && (rhs & 1) == 0)
            return lhs < rhs;
        else if((lhs & 1) == 1 && (rhs & 1) == 0)
            return true;
        else if((lhs & 1) == 1 && (rhs & 1) == 1)
            return rhs < lhs;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

...

std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, your_comparator<int>> your_pqueue;
```

Edit: Operator precedence.

Comment: Watch your operator precedence.

Comment: Nope. Those bitwise operators confuse everybody. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Yeah I've actually checked beforehand, but I did a quick `Ctrl+F` to lookup and missed the difference between `Address-of` and bitwise `&`.